# vectorizing a function to use entire dataframe column instead of single value

Tags: python, dataframe, vectorization

I have a function to set colors.  Currently, I loop through a dataframe and pass a single value to the function, cross reference that value to its corresponding color value and return the color value. I now want to pass the entire column from the dataframe (instead of looping through the dataframe) and return an array of color values.

Here is a simplified version of the function that currently works passing a single value (I just set the single value instead of showing the entire loop through the dataframe):

```
    def set_LineQualityColor(LineQ):
      data = [['grey', 0], ['cornflowerblue', 1], ['lightgreen', 2],['seagreen', 3], 
            ['mistyrose', 4], ['lightcoral', 4.1],['rosybrown', 5], ['indianred', 5.1], 
            ['lightgray', 9]]
      df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['CR', 'LineQuality'])   
      c=df[df['LineQuality']==LineQ]['CR'].values[0]
    return c
    
    LQ=4
    c= set_LineQualityColor(LQ)
```

How can I get this to work correctly when `LineQ` is a column from a dataframe? i.e.

```
c= set_LineQualityColor(df.LQ)
```

Or is there a more efficient way to go about doing this?  New to python.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set LineQuality as the index.

```
data = [['grey', 0], ['cornflowerblue', 1], ['lightgreen', 2],['seagreen', 3], 
            ['mistyrose', 4], ['lightcoral', 4.1],['rosybrown', 5], ['indianred', 5.1], 
            ['lightgray', 9]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['CR', 'LineQuality'])
df.set_index(['LineQuality'], drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Which gives this dataframe:

```
                         CR
LineQuality                
0.0                    grey
1.0          cornflowerblue
2.0              lightgreen
3.0                seagreen
4.0               mistyrose
4.1              lightcoral
5.0               rosybrown
5.1               indianred
9.0               lightgray
```

Then lookup using `loc`.

```
LQ_df = pd.DataFrame([1, 5, 4, 9, 4.1, 0, 4.0], columns=['LQ'])

LQ = LQ_df['LQ']

df.loc[LQ, 'CR']
```

Which gives this series:

```
LineQuality
1.0    cornflowerblue
5.0         rosybrown
4.0         mistyrose
9.0         lightgray
4.1        lightcoral
0.0              grey
4.0         mistyrose
```

It doesn't make sense to create the `df` dataframe every time you call the function, so it's better to create it once before calling the function. Then, you can define the function to use `df.loc` like we did before:

```
data = [['grey', 0], ['cornflowerblue', 1], ['lightgreen', 2],['seagreen', 3], 
            ['mistyrose', 4], ['lightcoral', 4.1],['rosybrown', 5], ['indianred', 5.1], 
            ['lightgray', 9]]

lineq_color_lookup = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['CR', 'LineQuality'])
lineq_color_lookup.set_index(['LineQuality'], drop=True, inplace=True)

def get_LineQualityColor(LineQ):
    return lineq_color_lookup.loc[LineQ, 'CR'] # .tolist() if you want it as a list
```

I also changed the function name to `get_LineQualityColor` because the function doesn't set anything -- it only returns the color corresponding to the given LineQuality.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a new (or column of) dataframe to join both to get result.

```
>>> def set_LineQualityColor_df(LineQ):
...     data = [['grey', 0], ['cornflowerblue', 1], ['lightgreen', 2],['seagreen', 3],
...             ['mistyrose', 4], ['lightcoral', 4.1],['rosybrown', 5], ['indianred', 5.1],
...             ['lightgray', 9]]
...     df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['CR', 'LineQuality'])
...     #c=df[df['LineQuality']==LineQ]['CR'].values[0]
...     c = df.set_index('LineQuality').join(LineQ)
...     return c
...
>>> df_lineQ = pd.DataFrame({ 'LineQuality': [4,5]})
>>> set_LineQualityColor_df(df_lineQ).head(5)
                     CR  LineQuality
LineQuality
0.0                    grey          4.0
1.0          cornflowerblue          5.0
2.0              lightgreen          NaN
3.0                seagreen          NaN
4.0               mistyrose          NaN
```

You can pass specific dataframe column.

```
>>> set_LineQualityColor_df(df_lineQ.LineQuality).head(5)
                         CR  LineQuality
LineQuality
0.0                    grey          4.0
1.0          cornflowerblue          5.0
2.0              lightgreen          NaN
3.0                seagreen          NaN
4.0               mistyrose          NaN
>>>
```